# Add values to an associative array in PHP

Tags: php

I want to append an element to to end of an associative array.

For example, my array is

```
$test=Array ([chemical] => asdasd [chemical_hazards] => ggggg )
```

and my result should be

```
$test=Array ([chemical] => asdasd [chemical_hazards] => ggggg [solution] => good)
```

Could you tell me how to implement this?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Just add it like you would with a non-associative array:

```
$test = array('chemical' => 'asdasd', 'chemical_hazards' => 'ggggg'); //init
$test['solution'] = 'good';
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with PHP's [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function.

```
$test = array('chemical' => 'asdasd', 'chemical_hazards' => 'ggggg'); 
$test2 = array('solution' => 'good');
$result = array_merge($test, $test2);
var_dump($result);
```